# VSC2013 Qt5 Addin で作成したプロジェクトをビルドするとエラーが発生する

Tags: c++, visual-studio, qt5

VSC2013 Qt5 Addin 1.2.4 で作成したQt Applicationプロジェクトをビルドすると以下の様なエラーが発生します。

```
> 1>------ ビルド開始: プロジェクト:testApp, 構成:Debug Win32 ------
> 1>qtmaind.lib(qtmain_win.obj) : error LNK2038: '_MSC_VER'
> の不一致が検出されました。値 '1600' が 1800 の値 'moc_mainwindow.obj' と一致しません。
> 1>C:\user\Qt5.VS2013\testApp\Win32\Debug\\testApp.exe : fatal error
> LNK1319: 1 の不一致が検出されました
> ========== ビルド: 0 正常終了、1 失敗、0 更新不要、0 スキップ ==========
```

ライブラリの VC++ のバージョンが違っているということみたいですが、この問題を対処するにはどうしたらいいのでしょうか？
自分で Qt Adin を VSC2013 でビルドし直すとか、Qt Addin の問題対処版が出るのを待つしかないのでしょうか？

Comment: 検索性を上げるため、qt5のタグを追加しました。

Comment: さんくすです。おいらはタグを追加できなかったので助かります。

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Qt Applicationプロジェクトに設定されたQtのバージョンが
Visual Studio 2013用のものになっていないのではないでしょうか？

[image: Qt Options]

手元の環境では上記のようにmsvc2013用のQt Versionsを設定した上で、Qt Applicationプロジェクトの[Qt Project Settings]にて下記のようにVersionを設定すると問題なくビルドできているように見えます。

[image: Qt Project Settings]

ただしテストしたのはプロジェクトの新規作成からQt Applicationを選択して、
プロジェクト作成ウィザードでは特に設定を変更せずにプロジェクトを作成した直後の状態です。
何か特別なライブラリをプロジェクト作成ウィザードで選択した場合にのみ発生するのかどうかは調査していません。